# Creating SQL users and restricting their permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

Greetings,

My program creates a SQL database using ADO.NET APIs to connect to a SQL server and manipulate SQL connections/transactions. When the database is created, I'm connecting to the server using 'sa' credentials. This will be the only time I will connect to the database using 'sa' credentials. During this same initial connection, I need to create a couple of logins and users, so that from there on credentials of these users will be used. Now, I know how I can create logins and users, but I cant seem to get restrictions of access right. Specifically, I need to create 1 db login and user that will have access to all stored procedured created for the database - sort of like a db admin, but very restricted (to only stored procs). And the second db login/user will be given access only to a couple of specific stored procs. Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Edited my post to add more details. Please feel free to ask if what I wrote is not clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a database role and then add the users to it. For the second user, I've included in the role and then denied permission to 2 sprocs. If you are denying permission to many sprocs and only granting permissions to a few sprocs, it may be better/easier to not include the second user in the role and individually grant permissions, for each object that you'd like to grant on. That's up to you and which way is most manageable for your situation.

```
--Replace db with your database name
USE db

--Create a database role
CREATE ROLE db_execonly

--Grant EXEC permissions to the role
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_execonly

--Add users to the new role
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_execonly', 'user1'
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_execonly', 'user2'

--Deny permissions to specific objects for user2
DENY EXEC ON OBJECT::dbo.usp_sproc1 TO user2
DENY EXEC ON OBJECT::dbo.usp_sproc2 TO user2
```

Comment: thanks, brian. im playing with both solutions, this one seems to be more elegant. i'll test it and post back the results

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a stored procedure that grants access to all stored procedures to a user :

[MS SQL Tips](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1203)

All you have to do is to call it with the user that needs to have rights to exec all stored procedures as parameter.

From this script you can see the GRANT used to allow access to a stored procedure is :

```
GRANT EXEC ON ' + '[' + @OwnerName + ']' + '.' + '[' + @ObjectName + ']' + ' TO ' + @user
```

**Edit : paste the stored procedure from the link**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGrantExectoAllStoredProcs @user sysname
AS

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Object Name: spGrantExectoAllStoredProcs
-- Author: Edgewood Solutions
-- Development Date: 03.19.2007
-- Called By: TBD
-- Description: Issue GRANT EXEC statement for all stored procedures
-- based on the user name that is passed in to this stored procedure
-- Project: SQL Server Security
-- Database: User defined databases
-- Business Process: SQL Server Security
-- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Num | CRF ID | Date Modified | Developer | Description
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- 001 | N\A      | 03.15.2007    | Edgewood | Original code for the GRANT
-- EXEC process
--
-- 
*/

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- 1 - Variable declarations
DECLARE @CMD1 varchar(8000)
DECLARE @MAXOID int
DECLARE @OwnerName varchar(128)
DECLARE @ObjectName varchar(128)

-- 2 - Create temporary table
CREATE TABLE #StoredProcedures
(OID int IDENTITY (1,1),
StoredProcOwner varchar(128) NOT NULL,
StoredProcName varchar(128) NOT NULL)

-- 3 - Populate temporary table
INSERT INTO #StoredProcedures (StoredProcOwner, StoredProcName)
SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_NAME NOT LIKE 'dt_%'
AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'

-- 4 - Capture the @MAXOID value
SELECT @MAXOID = MAX(OID) FROM #StoredProcedures

-- 5 - WHILE loop
WHILE @MAXOID > 0
BEGIN

-- 6 - Initialize the variables
SELECT @OwnerName = StoredProcOwner,
@ObjectName = StoredProcName
FROM #StoredProcedures
WHERE OID = @MAXOID

-- 7 - Build the string
SELECT @CMD1 = 'GRANT EXEC ON ' + '[' + @OwnerName + ']' + '.' + '[' + @ObjectName + ']' + ' TO ' + @user

-- 8 - Execute the string
-- SELECT @CMD1
EXEC(@CMD1)

-- 9 - Decrement @MAXOID
SET @MAXOID = @MAXOID - 1
END

-- 10 - Drop the temporary table
DROP TABLE #StoredProcedures

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Here it is.

All you need is to call this procedure with your sa user ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I need to be able to GRANT EXEC on ALL stored procs in the database in this manner.

Comment: @kateroh : that's what the stored procedure given in the link does :) But I didn't want to paste it since it's long. Ok I edit my post to paste it. I take the SQL Server 2005 version, if it's not the good one, go to the link.

Comment: @LaGandMere: thanks for your answer. Every time a new stored proc is added, this code will have to be re-run for all users, which is not very nice. Isnt the solution with a db role that is granted only 'execute' permissions more elegant (proposed by brian below)? Are there any drawbacks with his approach? Thanks!